# PHP function with global variables within an array

Tags: php

I have the following function that outputs some HTML (and located at top of code):

```
function linky( $slug4 ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'foot' => '<p class="one">Click Here</p>',
        'default'    => ''
    );

    return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug4 ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug4 ] : $class_map[ 'default' ];
}
```

At the `BODY`, I have some element with the following `PHP` code, and since it is already within the `HTML`, I open and close multiple `<?=` tags:

```
class="<?= flip('foo' ) ?> <?= con( 'foo' ) ?> bold" data-tab="/go/<?= $item[$i]["Name"] ?>/foo/?o" <?= modal( 'foo' ) ?>
```

I want to make the `Here` part of the first function, to contain all the above classes (so it will work like that other element) and be generated dynamically with PHP - How can I do that?

I  guess it should look something like:

```
'foot' => '<p class="one">Click <span class="flip('foo' ) con( 'foo' ) bold" data-tab="/go/$item[$i]["Name"]/foo/?o" modal( 'foo' )">Here</span></p>'
```

I've tried some combination of `'. .'` or using `"` but couldn't figure it out.

Also, should I add

`global $item,$i;`

To the function, since I'm including `$item[$i]["Name"]` ?

Comment: Dont use `global` - if your function needs external data to work, pass it in as an argument

Comment: Assign the function to variable, that should help you in concatenating

Comment: I''m afraid I would need a complete answer :/ don't have enough PHP knowledge